# Flutter Restore state

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Will Flutter handle's automatically restore state process for android
eg:-manages data in background which is yet not compleate...

I beleive flutter can automaically  handle  if  not will we required for both android and ios plese give a solution
Restore state
When a user runs a mobile app and then selects another app to run, the first app is moved to the background, or backgrounded. The operating system (both iOS and Android) might kill the backgrounded app to release memory and improve performance for the app running in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if the app is not terminated (killed by OS) the state will be persisted.

Otherwise, you'll have to fetch all the data again from the initial state.